# how to parse a string of comma-separated values into a list of strings in haskell?

Tags: haskell

so if I have a string "(this, is, a, story, all, about, how)" into a list of the words inside it ["this", "is", "a", "story", "all", "about", "how"] as an instance of ReadP String? I've tried a bunch of different ways, one of which being this:

```
parseStr :: ReadP String
parseStr = do
  skipSpaces
  n <- munch1 isAlphaOrDigit
  skipComma
  return $ n
```

which parses all values but the last. I thought if I combined it with this parse:

```
parseLast :: ReadP String
parseLast = do
  skipSpaces
  n <- munch1 isAlphaOrDigit
  return $ n
```

as

```
parseLet = (many parseStr) +++ parseLast
```

but that didn't work either. Any tips?

edit: more definitions

```
isAlphaOrDigit :: Char -> Bool 
isAlphaOrDigit a = (isDigit a) || (isAlpha a) 
comma = satisfy (','==)
skipComma = const () <$> some comma
```

Comment: Are the parentheses in `"(this, is, a, story, all, about, how)"` part of your input?

Comment: We also would need to see your definitions of `isAlphaOrDigit` and `skipComma`.

Comment: the parentheses are a part of the input, and here are the definitions: `isAlphaOrDigit :: Char -> Bool
isAlphaOrDigit a = (isDigit a) || (isAlpha a)`  `skipComma = const () <$> some comma`

Comment: `isAlphaOrDigit` and `skipComma` look fine. (I suggest you edit them into your question, for the sake of clarity.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser `a +++ b` sends the entire input string to `a` and the entire input string to `b`, producing all the results that either parser produced. You instead want a parser that sends the first part of the string to `a` and the second part to `b`, then lets you combine the results. Try this instead:

```
parseLet = liftA2 (\ss s -> ss ++ [s]) (many parseStr) parseLast
```

Many parser libraries also offer a `manySepBy` combinator (perhaps with a slightly different name) for this exact use case; you might consider looking through the `ReadP` library for such a thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! so I tried implementing your definition, but it ended up returning an empty list. I then tried to implement a new parseLet function using sepBy as :   `parseLet = do`
  `skipOpen`  
 `a <- sepBy parseStr comma`  
  `skipClose`
  `return $ a`   but this also only returned an empty list.

Comment: @jazaniac (1) You can use `between` from `Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP` to handle the parentheses. (2) A guess: have you removed the `skipComma` from `parseStr` before trying this `sepBy`-based version?

Comment: @duplode okay, now it looks like `parseLet = between open close (sepBy parseStr comma)`, it's still returning the emptylist though, unfortunately. And skipComma wasn't removed before, but I just removed it and it still returns an emptylist, unfortunately. `open = satisfy ('('==)`  `close = satisfy (')'==)`

Comment: @duplode wait nevermind! the problem was in my test case. Thanks!

Comment: @jazaniac You're welcome. A final note: you don't need `satisfy` for e.g. `satisfy ('('==)` -- just use `char '('` instead.