# Understanding Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP.sepBy1

Tags: parsing, haskell, parser-combinators

I am confused by the result of [sepBy1](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html#v:sepBy1)

Following code is running in ghci

```
λ> import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP
λ> import Data.Char

λ> readP_to_S ((munch1 isAlpha) `sepBy1` (char '-')) "dish-dash-dosh"
[(["dish"],"-dash-dosh"),(["dish","dash"],"-dosh"),["dish","dash","dosh"],"")]
```

1. Why it is not the case that output is `[(["dish","dash","dosh"],"")]`?

The following `doctest` is **only one** that failed.

```
-- |
-- >>> readP_to_S readValues "dish-dash-dosh"
-- [(V ["dish","dash","dosh"],"")
readValues :: ReadP Value
readValues = do
  xs <- (munch isAlpha) `sepBy1` (char '-')
  pure $ V xs
```

```
Main.hs:64: failure in expression `readP_to_S readValues "dish-dash-dosh"'
expected: [(V ["dish","dash","dosh"],"")
 but got: [(V ["dish"],"-dash-dosh"),(V ["dish","dash"],"-dosh"),(V ["dish","dash","dosh"],"")]
```

I am using `ReadP` for `Read` instance of my data. The code for `Read` instance is working but I am confused.

Haven't done any complex parsing, I always think that running `ReadP` will return output in form of single element list `[(result,"")]`, obviously it is not the case.

```
data Value = V [String]
  deriving Show

-- |
-- >>> read "dish-dash-dosh" :: Value
-- V ["dish","dash","dosh"]
--
instance Read Value where
  readPrec = readP_to_Prec (const readValues)
```

2. Is it the case that `read` will success only if there is nothing left in the `snd` of the last `[(Value,String)]`, other elements in this list are unuse anywhere?

I am aware of alternative [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40710600/how-to-parse-a-string-of-comma-separated-values-into-a-list-of-strings-in-haskel) to do this. This question is solely about understanding `sepBy` output and it usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running `ReadP` will return all the possible parses. You can restrict the number of valid parses by specifying what should happen after the `sepBy1` parse, e.g. end of input or some other syntactic element.

For instance, try something like:

```
readValues = do
  xs <- (munch isAlpha) `sepBy1` (char '-')
  eof
  pure $ V xs
```

Addendum...

The `ReadS` type follows the development of monadic parsing as presented in the classic Hutton and Meijer paper [Monadic Parsing in Haskell](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/pearl.pdf). From the little documentation there is, I gather that the `ReadP` implements parallel exploration of all alternatives. There is a lot of support for creating `ReadP` actions and not so much for `ReadS`, so I think you're using the library correctly by building a `ReadP` action and then using `readP_to_S` at the end. When I've used the module I've just taken the first match of the `ReadS` action (or returned a parse error if it was the empty list.)

The `ReadPrec` monad is used to support precedence, and it basically is `ReaderT Int ReadP` -- here the `Int` is the current precedence. Again, it looks like you start with a `ReadP` parser and then convert it to a `ReadPrec` action using `lift` or `readP_to_Prec`. To run it you can use `readPrec_to_S` just like in the `ReadP` case.

Comment: You were right, it was state in the [doc](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html#g:4) about list of all possible parses. There are lots of things in parsing (e.g., ReadP, ReadS, readPrec, readsPrec, readP_to_S, readP_to_Prec, ...), I still can't get the clear overview picture of how they are related. Do you have any additional recommend learning resources?

Comment: (Added more info about the `ReadS`, `ReadP` and `ReadPrec` types in the original response.)